# difference between TimeStamp values

Tags: android

Though my question would be a bit silly, but from long I am pondering over the difference between the timeStamped values which the sensor (accelerometer, gyros,etc.) in an Android phone gives via event.timeStamp and the values which System.nanotime() gives.

Practically both should be same as both gives the values from epoch in nanoseconds but for my case they are giving different, I am not able to exactly get this concept. Could someone throw some light.

Thanks